# Python Pandas Concatenate Vertically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm not entirely sure my title is accurate, I'm up for suggestions though.

Let's say I have a df that looks like this:

```
           file_names        searched_for  file_id_value
0          file_1.txt               a              0
6          file_2.txt               a              1
16         file_1.txt               b              2
20         file_2.txt               b              3
```

what I am interested in doing is having this output:

```
           file_names        searched_for  file_id_value
0          file_1.txt               a, b              0
1          file_2.txt               a, b              1
```

Is there a way to combine values like that? 
Joins and Merge aren't going to do it.

Comment: so commen question `df.groupby(['file_names'],as_index=False).agg({'searched_for':','.join,'file_id_value':'min'})
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by dictionary of columns and aggregate functions:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('file_names', as_index=False)
         .agg({'searched_for':','.join,'file_id_value':'first'}))
print (df1)
   file_names searched_for  file_id_value
0  file_1.txt          a,b              0
1  file_2.txt          a,b              1
```